# How to prevent user from typing input text ? Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

i need a solution, in the form of some directive or maybe you know what, to prevent the user from hitting a lot of spaces.

I am try with this link solutions:

https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/77d56d42-68ae-4a29-b239-0145da1c6852/y

But without success for my use case.

This is good solution but no work on my case:

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
export function removeSpaces(control: AbstractControl) {
  if (control && control.value && !control.value.replace(/\s/g, '').length) {
    control.setValue('');
  }
  return null;
}
```

I need to prevent to user can hitting space few times.. Example imagine input type text and i try to set John ________ John-TEST ________ TEst

___ is just space on keyboard...

I need to prevent it. Maybe directive ?

do you know the solution or the link to a solution?

Comment: try `value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')`

Comment: Use the library like  `ngx-mask`

Comment: @Andrei where to set value ? can you explain me better ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a directive with `@HostListener` to listen for space-key and combine it with `ElementRef` or `Input` to check the input text-value, so if last character is space, prevent event.

```
@HostListener('keydown.space', ['$event']) handler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(event);
    if (this.input.endsWith(' ')) {
       event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

** You can also remove `.space` and check the char in the event to see if space and then handle it.

Comment: what is input ?  Property 'input' does not exist on type

Comment: I mentioned it in the response, you can use @input decorator or you can inject elementRef into the constructor to access the input text-value. I have tried it and it works, give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired result by using the rxjs operators(`debounceTime`, `distinctUntilChanged`);

```
 this.searchField.valueChanges
  .pipe(debounceTime(800), distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
}
```

Comment: This si very good but i need global solution for all inputs in application

Comment: How to set this rxjs inside my directive ?

Comment: you just need to import the operators

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in simple HTML and JS as well. Or you can convert this to a JS logic

Here is sample html code for an input element

To alert user on entering multiple spaces:

```
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.match(/  +/g)) window.alert('Multiple Spaces Entered');">
```

Reduces multiple spaces to one single space immediately:

```
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.match(/  +/g)) this.value = this.value.replace(/  +/g, ' ');">
```

Comment: This si very good but i need global solution for all inputs in application

Comment: how about creating your own HTML element with this behavior. then instead of `<input />` you can use your own custom tag like - `<input-single-space />` ? example - https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-angular-6-custom-elements-web-components-c88814dc6e0a/

Answer (score -1):

Try this to replace multiple spaces with a single space.

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.control.valueChanges.subscribe((str: string) => {
      const newVal = str.replace( /  +/g, ' ' )
      this.control.setValue(newVal, {emitEvent: false});
 })
```

or you can create without-space directive:

```
export class WithoutSpacesDirective {
  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    const newVal = input.value.replace( /  +/g, ' ' )
    
    input.value = newVal; 
  }
}
```

html:

```
<input type="text" without-spaces [formControl]="control" />
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gxkr5a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This si very good but i need global solution for all inputs in application

Comment: i edited my answer